# Snowflake Dynamic Masking masks the column for all roles including the one I have unmasked

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am able to successfully create a masking policy and apply it to a column in a table.  However, the column ends up being masked for ALL roles including the role for which I unmasked the column.  See below for the code I wrote.  The PII_ROLE should not see the masked values in the table but that role also sees the masked values.  Any assistance with helping me to figure out where I erred would be greatly appreciated:

```
CREATE or replace masking policy masking_policies.ddm_policies.email_mask AS (val string) 
returns string ->

CASE 
        WHEN current_role() IN ('PII_ROLE') THEN val    
        ELSE '*MASKED*'
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the condition you put in when clause is failing, this could be a mismatch with role name PII_ROLE you specified. Check that it should be the correct name. Here is a small POC that you can use to validate your steps.

```
//Start of the POC 

use role accountadmin; //You can set any role that you want
 
create or replace database mydbtest;
use schema public;

create or replace table pinfo

(   FirstName  varchar(20),
    LastName   varchar(20),
    email      varchar(50) 
);

insert into pinfo values 
('Sarah', 'Janes','sarah.janes@hotmail.com'),
('Richard', 'Hays','richard.hays@gmail.com'),
('Maria', 'Khan','maria.khan@wow.com');

// masking policy to mask email column. Only ACCOUNTADMIN role can see the actual values
// all other will see the masked

create or replace masking policy email_mask as (val string) returns string ->
  case
    when current_role() in ('ACCOUNTADMIN') then val
    else '*MASKED*'
  end;
// Modify table and apply the policy   
alter table pinfo modify column email set masking policy email_mask;
// Query table you will see actual values in email column  
select * from pinfo;

// Now grant object access to role public
grant usage on database mydbtest to public;
grant usage on schema mydbtest.public to public;
grant select on pinfo to public;

// Set the role to public
use role public;
use schema public;
// Now Query table you will see the masked values in email column
select * from pinfo;
[Masked Values][1]
//Change the role back to ACCOUNTADMIN
use role accountadmin;
// You will see the actual values    
select * from pinfo;
[Actual Values][2]
```

Comment: I was able to solve it today!  The code I wrote was fine.  It was that I needed to apply the role to a user other than SYSADMIN.  I created a new user, assigned the role, and it all worked perfectly.  The new dynamic data masking is super easy.  I just didn't realize that has a "most restrictive type security" for the admin roles which is why it needed that new user / role.